# Simplifying manual data entry with a UserForm Excel 2010

Tags: beginner, vba, excel

I am an absolute beginner. This is the first thing I've ever coded in VBA. I don't know if I'm allowed to ask for just criticism in general without a question.

But just in case I can't, this file is going to get very large and I imagine I will have resource optimization problems - so what should I have done differently to compute these tasks efficiently?

The purpose of this code is to streamline some manual data entry I'm having to do at work. Basically, my department has a recruiting function and we post jobs on various websites. In order to develop some kind of metric, it is my job to record the performance data of jobs posted by all recruiters in department.

[image: A sample of the table]

I've created this form in order to put some of this work back on the recruiters as part of their job posting workflow.

```
Public reqnum As String
Public jbtitle As String
Public jbloc As String
Public postdate As String
Public closedate As String
Public vws As Integer
Public apps As Integer
Public jobcategory As String
Public pidname As String

'If someone hits enter on the last textbox, it will submit the form
Private Sub ApplicantsBox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Call UpdateButton_Click
    End If
End Sub

'If someone hits enter while focused on the check box, they will change its value
Private Sub GoToCheckbox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        If GoToCheckbox.Value = True Then
            GoToCheckbox.Value = False
        Else
            GoToCheckbox.Value = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    'Establish variables with textbox values
    reqnum = ReqNumBox.Value
    jbtitle = JobTitleBox.Value
    jbloc = JobLocationBox.Value
    postdate = DatePostedBox.Value
    closedate = DateClosedBox.Value
    jobcategory = CategoryComboBox.Value
    pidname = PIDComboBox.Value

    'Check to make sure data in views and applications is a number
    If Not IsNumeric(ViewsBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("You put in a non-number for Views")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        vws = ViewsBox.Value
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(ApplicantsBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("You put in a non-number for Applications")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        apps = ApplicantsBox.Value
    End If

    'Check to see if the user selected other as either a job category or name
    Call AddToDirectory

    'Decision Tree for a search by either reqnum or job title, location and post date
    If Not reqnum = "" Then
        Dim reqnum_row As Long
        reqnum_row = 0

        'Search mechanism for requisition numbers
        For Each c In Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
            If c.Value = reqnum Then
                reqnum_row = c.row
            End If
        Next c

        'if there isn't an exisiting req...
        If reqnum_row = 0 Then
            'Set a variable as the last row with text
            Dim rw As Long
            rw = LastRowInOneColumn("D", 1)
            'Establish the first empty row
            Dim newrow As Long
            newrow = rw + 1

            'Add information to row
            Call UpdateCellData(newrow)

            'Format the row with alternating background color
            Call FormatRows(newrow)
            Call CloseForm(newrow)

        Else
            Call UpdateCellData(reqnum_row)
            Call CloseForm(reqnum_row)
        End If


    Else
        'Logic for if there is not a reqnum
        Dim job_row As Long
        job_row = 0
        'Search mechanism for search by job title then location then post date.
        'If all given data equals all the same in a row it will be selected as the row to update
        For Each X In Sheets(1).Range("B:B")
            If X.Value = jbtitle Then
                If X.Offset(0, 1).Value = jbloc Then
                    If X.Offset(0, 2).Value = postdate Then
                        job_row = X.row
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next X

        'If the search comes up empty add a new row of data
        If job_row = 0 Then
            'Set a variable as last row with text
            Dim rwj As Long
            rwj = LastRowInOneColumn("D", 1)
            'set a variable as first row without text
            Dim newrowj As Long
            newrowj = rwj + 1

            Call UpdateCellData(newrowj)

            'Formatting the rows
            Call FormatRows(newrowj)
            Call CloseForm(newrowj)
        Else
            Call UpdateCellData(job_row)
            Call CloseForm(job_row)
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Function LastRowInOneColumn(column As String, ws As Long) As Long
'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    Dim lastrow As Long
    With Sheets(ws)
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, column).End(xlUp).row
    End With
    LastRowInOneColumn = lastrow
End Function

Sub UpdateCellData(n As Long)
    'Add information to the rows
    'if the textbox is blank or is zero, do nothing.
        With Sheets(1)
            If Not reqnum = "" Or reqnum = " " Then
                .Cells(n, 1).Value = reqnum
            End If
            If Not jbtitle = "" Or jbtitle = " " Then
                .Cells(n, 2).Value = jbtitle
            End If
            If Not jbloc = "" Or jbloc = " " Then
                .Cells(n, 3).Value = jbloc
            End If
            If Not postdate = "" Or postdate = " " Then
                .Cells(n, 4).Value = postdate
            End If
            If Not closedate = "" Or closedate = " " Then
                .Cells(n, 5).Value = closedate
            End If
            If Not vws = 0 Then
                .Cells(n, 7).Value = vws
            End If
            If Not apps = 0 Then
                .Cells(n, 8).Value = apps
            End If
            If Not jobcategory = "<Update>" Then
                .Cells(n, 11) = jobcategory
            End If
            If Not pidname = "<Update>" Then
                .Cells(n, 12) = pidname
            End If
        End With
End Sub


Function IsEven(z As Long) As Boolean
    If z Mod 2 = 0 Then
        IsEven = True
    Else
        IsEven = False
    End If

End Function

Sub CloseForm(w As Long)
    If GoToCheckbox.Value = True Then
        Sheets(1).Activate
        Sheets(1).Rows(w).Select
        Unload Me
    Else
        With ReqNumBox
            .SetFocus
            .SelStart = 0
            .SelLength = Len(.Text)
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateButton_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        Call UpdateButton_Click
    End If
End Sub

Sub FormatRows(rowtoformat As Long)
    'Extend Formulas
    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("F3:F" & rowtoformat).FillDown
        .Range("I3:I" & rowtoformat).FillDown
        .Range("J3:J" & rowtoformat).FillDown
    End With

    'Format Rows
    Dim even As Boolean
    even = IsEven(rowtoformat)
    If even = True Then
        Sheets(1).Rows(4).Copy
        Sheets(1).Rows(rowtoformat).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
    Else
        Sheets(1).Rows(5).Copy
        Sheets(1).Rows(rowtoformat).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()


    'Find the last row in column a
    a = LastRowInOneColumn("A", 2)

    'Iterate through all PI Data options
    For Each z In Worksheets("Hidden Data Storage").Range("A2:A" & a)
        With PIDComboBox
            .AddItem (z)
        End With
    Next z

    b = LastRowInOneColumn("B", 2)
    For Each w In Worksheets("Hidden Data Storage").Range("B2:B" & b)
        With CategoryComboBox
            .AddItem (w)
        End With
    Next w
End Sub

Sub AddToDirectory()
    'Checks to see if the person selected "Other" as the value for either PID or Category
    If pidname = "Other" Then

        Dim newname As String
        newname = InputBox("Please add your name: ")

        'adds new name to directory
        With Worksheets("Hidden Data Storage")
            Dim v As Long
            v = LastRowInOneColumn("A", 2)
            Dim vadd As Long
            vadd = v + 1

            .Cells(vadd, 1).Value = newname
        End With
    End If

    'Checks to see if "other" is selected as job category
    If jobcategory = "Other" Then
        Dim newcategory As String
        'asks for new category
        newcategory = InputBox("Please add the new category: ")

        'adds new category to the hidden directory
        With Worksheets("Hidden Data Storage")
            Dim h As Long
            h = LastRowInOneColumn("B", 2)
            Dim hadd As Long
            hadd = h + 1

            .Cells(hadd, 2).Value = newcategory
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Very fine effort and I see very little to change for efficiency reasons.

If it does start to slow down during your updates, you could turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating` and turn it back on after the UserForm has initialized.

But I don't see that as an issue now.

Some small suggestions below - I don't think they will do much for speed - but address readibility, maintenance and efficiency.

> **Improve readability by using predefined and system constants**

**EDIT - use constant at top for Carriage Return**
`Public Const CR    As Integer = 13`

**Then Replace all checks for**
`KeyCode = 13`
with 
`KeyCode = CR`

> **Simplify**

**Change:**
    `If GoToCheckbox.Value = True Then
        GoToCheckbox.Value = False
    Else
        GoToCheckbox.Value = True
    End If`

**To (just make sure you have default value = 0)**
`GoToCheckbox.Value = Not GoToCheckbox.Value`

> **Practice common or even standard coding practice**

- **Move your Dims to top of function/sub code**

> **Simplify logical comparisons**

- no need to compare to true - or even to use a variable if you have a well-named function that indicates it returns true/false
- continue to reference Sheets using With

**Example:**

**Change**

```
Sub FormatRows(rowtoformat As Long)
    'Extend Formulas
    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("F3:F" & rowtoformat).FillDown
        .Range("I3:I" & rowtoformat).FillDown
        .Range("J3:J" & rowtoformat).FillDown
    End With

    'Format Rows
    Dim even As Boolean
    even = IsEven(rowtoformat)
    If even = True Then
        Sheets(1).Rows(4).Copy
        Sheets(1).Rows(rowtoformat).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
    Else
        Sheets(1).Rows(5).Copy
        Sheets(1).Rows(rowtoformat).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
    End If
End Sub
```

**To**

```
Sub FormatRows(rowtoformat As Long)

    'Extend Formulas
    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("F3:F" & rowtoformat).FillDown
        .Range("I3:I" & rowtoformat).FillDown
        .Range("J3:J" & rowtoformat).FillDown

        'Format Rows    
        If IsEven(rowtoformat) Then
            .Rows(4).Copy
        Else
            .Rows(5).Copy
        End If
        .Rows(rowtoformat).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
    End With

End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for the improvements. What is vbCr?

Comment: It's a VBA constant. Oops - that probably won't work - I just realized it's not 13 - it's CHR(13) - the actual ASCII key - I'll update my edit to use a constant at the top instead

Answer (score 1):

### Performance

> "I imagine I will have resource optimisation problems"

You'll be fine. To repeat a widespread programming mantra:

> "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil"

Just build your thing, and build it well, and **if** you encounter performance problems down the line, **then** start worrying about optimising for performance.

That aside, some general VBA performance tips:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.EnaleEvents
Application.Calculation
Application.StatusBar
```

If your application doesn't need events to fire, or doesn't need formulas to recalculate during execution, or your user doesn't need to see what's going on, you can turn those settings off as appropriate during the start of a Sub/Function and reset it at the end.

ScreenUpdating in particular will generally makes a huge difference.

---

### Naming

Your naming is actually pretty decent, but could still be better.

Names should be **Descriptive**, then **Unambiguous** and **only then** concise. Your names should be written to be **understood** as easily as possible. Not read quickly, understood quickly.

`jbtitle` vs `jobTitle`

It takes just one additional character to transform it from an abbreviation I have to decode, to a name I can just read.

`jbloc` vs `jobLocation`

Again, takes a fraction of a second longer to read, is **much** easier to understand.

`vws`

What on earth is that? I have no idea. I had to go hunting through your code to figure it out. Just call it `viewBoxValue` and you'll never have a problem understanding what it is and what it's doing in your code.

`apps` vs `numApplicants`

Again, fractionally longer to read, so much easier to understand what's going on.

`pidname`

I don't actually know what these PID values are meant to represent. It's not in your code. I recommend something more descriptive.

**Magic Numbers**

```
If KeyCode = 13 Then
```

What is the significance of 13? Make it an appropriately named constant and you'll never need to look it up further down the line.

```
Public Const ENTER_KEY_KEYCODE As Long = 13

...

If keyCode = ENTER_KEY_KEYCODE Then
```

And now your code is completely self-explanatory.

This rule applies to any hard-coded value that appears in your code. Whenever you see a number, or a string, or anything hardcoded, ask yourself igf it couldn't be put in a variable instead.

**Naming Conventions**

Naming Conventions are incredibly useful, when applied consistently, because they allow you to embed metaData in your code and to easily *see* unusual variables / potential errors.

Standard VBA conventions go thus:

> **Local Variables:** Written in `camelCase`.
>
> `Dim localVariable As String`
>   includes method arguments.
>
> **Module / Global Variables:** Written in `PascalCase`.
>
> `Private ModuleVariable As String`
>   `Public GlobalVariable As Long`
>
> **Method Names:** Verbs. Written in `PascalCase`
>
> `Private Function ReturnThisValue() As Long`
>   `Public Sub DoThisThing()`
>
> **Constants:** Written in `SHOUTY_SNAKE_CASE`
>
> `Public Const CONSTANT_VALUE As String = "This Value Never Changes"`

---

### Refactoring

Big things are made up of lots of little things. Little things are made up of even smaller things. The art of programming is taking one big thing, and splitting it up into many different steps which, when brought together, give you the result you want.

If you ever find yourself writing a comment that says **what** your code is doing

```
'Check to make sure data in views and applications is a number
```

that's a good sign that the thing should be put into its' own, appropriately named, Sub/Function.

---

```
'If someone hits enter while focused on the check box, they will change its value
Private Sub GoToCheckbox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    If KeyCode = 13 Then
        If GoToCheckbox.Value = True Then
            GoToCheckbox.Value = False
        Else
            GoToCheckbox.Value = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

First off, that comment, if it should be anywhere, should be **inside** the function it refers to. Using our previous point about `Constants` and a little simplification to do with `Boolean` values, we can change it to this:

```
Private Sub GoToCheckbox_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    If KeyCode = ENTER_KEY_KEYCODE Then
        With gotocheckbox
            .Value = Not .Value
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

And now the comment is pretty redundant because the code quite literally says what it does.

---

```
Public Function IsEven(z As Long) As Boolean
    If z Mod 2 = 0 Then
        IsEven = True
    Else
        IsEven = False
    End If

End Function
```

This can be similarly simplified

```
Public Function IsEven(ByVal checkValue As Double) As Boolean

    IsEven = (checkValue Mod 2 = 0)

End Function
```

---

And now we get to something we can really sink our teeth into.

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
    'Establish variables with textbox values
    reqnum = ReqNumBox.Value
    jbtitle = JobTitleBox.Value
    jbloc = JobLocationBox.Value
    postdate = DatePostedBox.Value
    closedate = DateClosedBox.Value
    jobcategory = CategoryComboBox.Value
    pidname = PIDComboBox.Value

    'Check to make sure data in views and applications is a number
    If Not IsNumeric(ViewsBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("You put in a non-number for Views")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        vws = ViewsBox.Value
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(ApplicantsBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("You put in a non-number for Applications")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        apps = ApplicantsBox.Value
    End If

    'Check to see if the user selected other as either a job category or name
    Call AddToDirectory

    'Decision Tree for a search by either reqnum or job title, location and post date
    If Not reqnum = "" Then
        Dim reqnum_row As Long
        reqnum_row = 0

        'Search mechanism for requisition numbers
        For Each c In Sheets(1).Range("A:A")
            If c.Value = reqnum Then
                reqnum_row = c.Row
            End If
        Next c

        'if there isn't an exisiting req...
        If reqnum_row = 0 Then
            'Set a variable as the last row with text
            Dim rw As Long
            rw = LastRowInOneColumn("D", 1)
            'Establish the first empty row
            Dim newrow As Long
            newrow = rw + 1

            'Add information to row
            Call UpdateCellData(newrow)

            'Format the row with alternating background color
            Call FormatRows(newrow)
            Call CloseForm(newrow)

        Else
            Call UpdateCellData(reqnum_row)
            Call CloseForm(reqnum_row)
        End If


    Else
        'Logic for if there is not a reqnum
        Dim job_row As Long
        job_row = 0
        'Search mechanism for search by job title then location then post date.
        'If all given data equals all the same in a row it will be selected as the row to update
        For Each X In Sheets(1).Range("B:B")
            If X.Value = jbtitle Then
                If X.Offset(0, 1).Value = jbloc Then
                    If X.Offset(0, 2).Value = postdate Then
                        job_row = X.Row
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next X

        'If the search comes up empty add a new row of data
        If job_row = 0 Then
            'Set a variable as last row with text
            Dim rwj As Long
            rwj = LastRowInOneColumn("D", 1)
            'set a variable as first row without text
            Dim newrowj As Long
            newrowj = rwj + 1

            Call UpdateCellData(newrowj)

            'Formatting the rows
            Call FormatRows(newrowj)
            Call CloseForm(newrowj)
        Else
            Call UpdateCellData(job_row)
            Call CloseForm(job_row)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

First off, see this?

```
    'Establish variables with textbox values
    reqnum = ReqNumBox.Value
    jbtitle = JobTitleBox.Value
    jbloc = JobLocationBox.Value
    postdate = DatePostedBox.Value
    closedate = DateClosedBox.Value
    jobcategory = CategoryComboBox.Value
    pidname = PIDComboBox.Value
```

This needs to be a `Class Object`. Let's create a Class called `Job_Posting_Details` or something similar and make all of those things `Properties`. Then we can just pass around a `Job_Posting_Details` Object instead of all of these variables.

`Insert --> Class Module` and then:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type JobPostingDetails
    RequisitionNumber As Long
    jobTitle As String
    jobLocation As String
    dateJobPosted As Date
    datePostingClosed As Date
    jobCategory As String
    pidName As String
End Type
Private this As JobPostingDetails

Public Property Let RequisitionNumber(ByVal inputValue As Long)
    this.RequisitionNumber = inputValue
End Property
Public Property Get RequisitionNumber() As Long
    RequisitionNumber = this.RequisitionNumber
End Property
```

With Property `Let/Get` for all the other properties:

```
Public Property Let JobTitle(ByVal inputValue As String)
    this.JobTitle = inputValue
End Property
Public Property Get JobTitle() As String
    JobTitle = this.JobTitle
End Property

Public Property Let JobLocation(ByVal inputValue As String)
    this.JobLocation = inputValue
End Property
Public Property Get JobLocation() As String
    JobLocation = this.JobLocation
End Property

Public Property Let DateJobPosted(ByVal inputValue As Date)
    this.DateJobPosted = inputValue
End Property
Public Property Get DateJobPosted() As Date
    DateJobPosted = this.DateJobPosted
End Property

Public Property Let DatePostingClosed(ByVal inputValue As Date)
    this.DatePostingClosed = inputValue
End Property
Public Property Get DatePostingClosed() As Date
    DatePostingClosed = this.DatePostingClosed
End Property

Public Property Let JobCategory(ByVal inputValue As String)
    this.JobCategory = inputValue
End Property
Public Property Get JobCategory() As String
    JobCategory = this.JobCategory
End Property

Public Property Let PidName(ByVal inputValue As String)
    this.PidName = inputValue
End Property
Public Property Get PidName() As String
    PidName = this.PidName
End Property
```

And now we can do things like this:

```
Dim jobDetails As Job_Posting_Details
Set jobDetails = New Job_Posting_Details

With jobDetails
    .RequisitionNumber = CLng(ReqNumBox.Text)
    .JobTitle = JobTitleBox.Text
    .JobLocation = JobLocationBox.Text
    .DateJobPosted = CDate(DatePostedBox.Text)
    .DatePostingClosed = CDate(DateClosedBox.Text)
    .JobCategory = CategoryComboBox.Text
    .PidName = PIDComboBox.Text
End With

AddToDirectory jobDetails

Public Sub AddToDirectory(Byref jobDetails As Job_Posting_Details)
    'Checks to see if the person selected "Other" as the value for either PID or Category

    If jobDetails.PidName = "Other" Then

        Dim newname As String
        newname = InputBox("Please add your name: ")

        'adds new name to directory
        With Worksheets("Hidden Data Storage")
            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("A", 2)

            Dim printRow As Long
            printRow = lastRow + 1

            .Cells(printRow, 1).Value = newname
        End With
    End If

    If jobDetails.JobCategory = "Other" Then

        Dim newcategory As String
        'asks for new category
        newcategory = InputBox("Please add the new category: ")

        'adds new category to the hidden directory
        With Worksheets("Hidden Data Storage")

            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = LastRowInOneColumn("B", 2)

            Dim printRow As Long
            printRow = lastRow + 1

            .Cells(printRow, 2).Value = newcategory
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Or, you might even make `AddToDirectory` a method of jobDetails itself (In the class module):

```
Public Sub AddToDirectory()

    Const OTHER_PID_TEXT As String = "other"
    Const PID_NAME_COLUMN As Long = 1

    Const OTHER_CATEGORY_TEXT As String = "Other"
    Const JOB_CATEGORY_COLUMN As Long = 2

    Dim directorySheet As Worksheet
    Set directorySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hidden Data Storage")

    Dim printRow As Long
    With directorySheet

        If this.PidName = OTHER_PID_TEXT Then

            printRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, PID_NAME_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(printRow, PID_NAME_COLUMN) = InputBox("Please add your name: ")

        End If

        If this.JobCategory = OTHER_CATEGORY_TEXT Then

            printRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, JOB_CATEGORY_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Cells(printRow, JOB_CATEGORY_COLUMN) = InputBox("Please add the new category: ")

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

And then your original sub goes:

```
    Dim jobDetails As Job_Posting_Details
    Set jobDetails = New Job_Posting_Details

    With jobDetails
        .RequisitionNumber = CLng(ReqNumBox.Text)
        .JobTitle = JobTitleBox.Text
        .JobLocation = JobLocationBox.Text
        .DateJobPosted = CDate(DatePostedBox.Text)
        .DatePostingClosed = CDate(DateClosedBox.Text)
        .JobCategory = CategoryComboBox.Text
        .PidName = PIDComboBox.Text
    End With

    jobDetails.AddToDirectory
```

Now this:

```
    'Check to make sure data in views and applications is a number
    If Not IsNumeric(ViewsBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("You put in a non-number for Views")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        vws = ViewsBox.Value
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(ApplicantsBox.Value) Then
        MsgBox ("You put in a non-number for Applications")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        apps = ApplicantsBox.Value
    End If
```

Needs to be a separate validation function. Like so:

```
Public Function ValidateViewboxValue(ByVal viewBoxValue As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim isValid As Boolean
    isValid = IsNumeric(viewBoxValue)

    If Not isValid Then
        MsgBox ("You put in a non-number for Views")
    End If

    ValidateViewboxValue = isValid

End Function
```

And then:

```
    Dim viewBoxValue As Variant
    viewBoxValue = viewsbox.Value

    If Not ValidateViewboxValue(viewBoxValue) Then Exit Sub
```

And now, if our validation requirements ever change, we can go straight to `ValidateViewboxValue` without worrying about the rest of the code.

---

There's lots more I'd like to say, but this review is getting a bit long and there's plenty here to work with already. I especially recommend building a Class or 2 for your userform.

Comment: Thank you for the review. That was really insightful, I'll have to learn more about classes. Also, for variable names, is it appropriate to use variables like z, w, x, etc. for the loops?

Comment: If your variables are **literally** no more meaningful than iterating over an array index, then `x, y, z` are conventional. But in most cases, even there, something like `currentIndex` or `currentRow` or `somethingCounter` would be better.

Comment: Just noticed you used `ReqNumBox.Text`, and etc. for the other textboxes, instead of `.Value`, was I using `.Value` incorrectly or is there a benefit to `.Text`?

Comment: @RollTideBrad I prefer `.Text` because then I **know** the result is going to come out as a `String`. If I use `.Value` then it could get coerced to all sorts of things.